# Display image at original color in tabbar- iphone

Tags: iphone, image, colors, icons, tabbar

I want to set an image for tabbar icon with its original color.

Currently When an image set to tabbar icon then it changes to blue when selected and grey for unselected state. How can i display it with its original color

Comment: I got the answer from the following stack over flow question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361851/iphonecolor-of-tabbar-image